# How to use regex inside in query using morphia?

Tags: regex, mongodb, morphia

Mongodb allows regex expression of pattern /pattern/ without using $regex expression.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

How can i do it using morphia ?

If i give Field criteria with field operator as in and value of type "java.util.regex.Pattern"  then the equivalent query generated in 
$in:[$regex: 'given pattern'] which wont return expected results at all.

Expectation: $in :[ /pattern1 here/,/pattern2 here/]
Actual using 'Pattern' object : $in : [$regex:/pattern1 here/,$regex:/pattern 2 here/]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what to make of your code examples, but here's a working Morphia code snippet:

```
Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("^" + email + "$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
mongoDatastore.find(EmployeeEntity.class).filter("email", regexp).get();
```

Note that this is really slow. It can't use an index and will always require a full collection scan, so avoid it at all cost!

**Update**: I've added a specific code example. The `$in` is not required to search inside an array. Simply use `/^I/` as you would in string:

```
> db.profile.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac3fa63f282f56de64bd"),
  "tags": [
    "India",
    "Australia",
    "Indonesia"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac4da63f282f56de64be"),
  "tags": [
    "Island",
    "Antigua"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac5ca63f282f56de64bf"),
  "tags": [
    "Spain",
    "Mexico"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac6da63f282f56de64c0"),
  "tags": [
    "Israel"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ad17a63f282f56de64c1"),
  "tags": [
    "Germany",
    "Indonesia"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ad56a63f282f56de64c2"),
  "tags": [
    "ireland"
  ]
}
> db.profile.find({ tags: /^I/ })
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac3fa63f282f56de64bd"),
  "tags": [
    "India",
    "Australia",
    "Indonesia"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac4da63f282f56de64be"),
  "tags": [
    "Island",
    "Antigua"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ac6da63f282f56de64c0"),
  "tags": [
    "Israel"
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("54f3ad17a63f282f56de64c1"),
  "tags": [
    "Germany",
    "Indonesia"
  ]
}
```

Note: The position in the array makes no difference, but the search is case sensitive. Use `/^I/i` if this is not desired or `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` in Java.

Comment: but wont the above generate an equivalent mongodb query as    "email" :[ "$regex" : "/^email/" ] ?

Comment: What's the document you're trying to get? I'm not clear what the connection between $in and the regular expression is in your question

Comment: db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: [ /^be/ ] } } )                                         How do i write a query like this using morphia ?                                         The one you suggested  will generate something like this                         db.inventory.find({tags:[$regex:/^be/]}) which is not that i expect..                   Let me know if i am not clear enough.

Comment: what does the document look like you are searching?

Comment: Profile collection contains a document has a field called tags for eg: tags:['India','Australia','Indonesia'] I am trying to search for all documents that contain tags which has one value that starts with 'I' . which is like the executing the following query            db.profile.find({'tags':{ $in : [ /^I/ ] } })   What is the morphia equivalent for this ?

Comment: You don't need the ``$in``. I've added a code example with the regular regexp syntax. This is easier to showcase on the shell, but will work the same way from Morphia

Answer (score 3):

**Single RegEx Filter**

use `.filter()`, `.criteria()`, or `.field()`

```
query.filter("email", Pattern.compile("reg.*exp"));
// or
query.criteria("email").contains("reg.*exp");
// or
query.field("email").contains("reg.*exp");
```

Morphia converts this into:

```
find({"email": { $regex: "reg.*exp" } })
```

**Multiple RegEx Filters**

```
query.or(
    query.criteria("email").contains("reg.*exp"),
    query.criteria("email").contains("reg.*exp.*2"),
    query.criteria("email").contains("reg.*exp.*3")
);
```

Morphia converts this into:

```
find({"$or" : [ 
            {"email": {"$regex": "reg.*exp"}},
            {"email": {"$regex": "reg.*exp.*2"}},
            {"email": {"$regex": "reg.*exp.*3"}}
        ]
    })
```

Unfortunately,

> You cannot use $regex operator expressions inside an $in.
>   [MongoDB Manual 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-with-a-regular-expression)

Otherwise, we could do:

```
Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[] {
    Pattern.compile("reg.*exp"),
    Pattern.compile("reg.*exp.*2"),
    Pattern.compile("reg.*exp.*3"),
};
query.field().in(patterns);
```

hopefully, one day morphia will support that :)